# Change display format of date timestamp in PySpark

Tags: python, date, pyspark, format

I am having a DataFrame, where initially I had a string to dates. I converted it into proper timestamp with `to_timestamp` function. The `schema` of the DataFrame shows that it is a `timestamp`.

**Q:** How can I format the display `date` column to display dates in `MMM-YYYY` format like `JAN-2015` instead of `2015-01-01 00:00:00`?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, date_format 
valuesCol = [('01JAN2015',),('01FEB2018',),('01APR2013',),('01DEC2016',)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['date'])
df = df.withColumn('date',to_timestamp('date','ddMMMyyyy'))
df.show()
df.printSchema()
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|2015-01-01 00:00:00|
|2018-02-01 00:00:00|
|2013-04-01 00:00:00|
|2016-12-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+

root
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I cannot use `date_format()` function because the resulting datatype is `string`.

```
df=df.withColumn("date",date_format('date',"MMM-yyyy"))
df.show()
df.printSchema() 
+--------+
|    date|
+--------+
|Jan-2015|
|Feb-2018|
|Apr-2013|
|Dec-2016|
+--------+

root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

So, in nutshell, how can I change the display format of `date` while maintaining it's datatype as `timestamp`?

Comment: It is not possible to maintain the `timestamp` datatype and display it as you want. Why does it matter anyway? (It's the same as asking how to keep a column of `integer` type but display it as a decimal.) Keep it as a timestamp, but when you display it, convert to a string. Or create a new column for display purposes.

Comment: Normally in SAS you have the option to choose a format, so being a dried in wool SAS developer, I thought there might be same thing in Python/PySpark too. It would have been good to atleast truncate the seconds anyway, else the output time stamp is too long. Thanks Pault for your comments. Always appreciated.

Comment: So I shouldn't say it's not possible- it *is* possible, but it wouldn't be easy. You could write your own user defined type or a decorator for the `DataFrame.show()` method.

Comment: In Python such a thing has been marked as an enhancement - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11501. So, I can understand that this feature is still pending in Spark.